# Can there be 2 limits to an $x$ value?

Tags: limits

Given function $g(x)$ and its graph below, I need to find $$\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)$$
Empty white dot means a limit. Judging from the graph it looks like there're 2 limits when $x\to 1$, that is $0$ and $2$. Is this correct?

[image: graph]

Comment: Lookup [lateral limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit).

Comment: If you're asking about what happens in the real numbers, the answer is **no**: the limit, in case it exists, is *unique*. In your case, and assuming the first vertical dotted line from the left represents one, the limit does *not* exist as the left sided one doesn't equal the right sided one.

Comment: "Empty white dot means a limit." No, you have misunderstood. There is a subtle difference in what a white dot means that seems to be leading to your confusion. An empty white dot means that the function is not defined to have that y-value at that x-value, and instead has the y-value of the black dot on the same vertical line. So the two white dots at x=1 do not mean that the function has "two limits" there, though it does have a *left-hand* and a *right-hand* limit there by happenstance, but rather that the function is defined to have y=0 at the point x=1 rather than having y=-1 or y=1.

Comment: @AntonioVargas thank you for the explanation! Indeed I didn't recognize that there's just a right-hand and left-hand limit but the $x\to 1$  doesn't have a limit.

Comment: My point is that the white/black dots are something more fundamental / elementary about the function: they talk about just what its values are. Limits, if they exist, can be *deduced* from plots like this, but at a basic level the black and white dots don't say anything about limits by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the graph we can say that
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}g(x)=1 (\mbox{right limit}),\quad \lim_{x\to 1^-}g(x)=-1 (\mbox{left limit})$$
and the $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)$ does not exists (if it exists then it is unique).

Answer (score 0):

If I well interpret the figure the function have two different limits, from left and from right at $x \to 1$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-}g(x)=-1 \qquad \lim_{x \to 1^+}g(x)=1
$$

and the value ofthe function at $x=1$ is $g(1)=0$, different from the two limits.